# how to indexing pandas dataframe with index list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe like the belows.

```
df
   a  b  c
w  5  3  3
x  4  7  6
y  6  2  5
z  2  6  2
```

And I have a list like belows.

```
a
[['w', 'x', 'w'], 
['x', 'y', 'y']]
```

How can I get the results like

```
[[5,7,3],
[4,2,5]]
```

If the only way is using a for loop, which is the fastest way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think for loop should be fast enough

```
[[df.loc[z,y] for z,y in zip(x,df.columns)] for x in l ]
Out[981]: [[5, 7, 3], [4, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: `df.at` instead.

Comment: Thank u so much. I use the df.at version.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming length of sub-lists are always the same as the length of columns

```
[[*df.lookup(i, df.columns)] for i in a]

[[5, 7, 3], [4, 2, 5]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. df.at is definitely faster than df.loc